# Mocking a service dependency in an Angular controller with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've been trying to get started with unit testing in angular with karma and jasmine, and i've been pulling my hair out trying to wrap my head around how to test controllers with dependencies. I tried mocking a spy with a jasmine spyObj and registering it in the beforeEach hook, but for some reason the spy isn't being recognized.

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('testModule', [])
.controller('TestController', [
    '$scope',
    'TestService',
    function ($scope, TestService) {
        $scope.data = TestService.load();
    }])

.factory('TestService', function () {
    return {
        load: function(){
            return "foo";
        }
    }
});
```

and here's the test

```
describe('TestController', function() {

var $controller, $scope, TestService;

beforeEach(module('testModule'), function($provide){
    TestService = jasmine.createSpyObj("TestService", ["load"]);
    TestService.load.andReturn("bar");
    $provide.value("TestService", TestService)
});

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _TestService_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    TestService = _TestService_;
    $controller = _$controller_('TestController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        TestService: TestService
    });
}));

it('should set $scope.data to bar when TestService.load is called', function() {
    expect(TestService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($scope.data).toEqual("bar");
}); });
```

Both assertions in the test fail.

I get 'Error: Expected a spy, but got Function' when i call         expect(TestService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();

and if I call expect($scope.data).toEqual("bar"), I get Expected 'foo' to equal 'bar'.  "Foo" is coming from the actual service, not the spy object.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `jasmine.createSpyObj`, it will be easier to use the existing service that the `$injector` provides and then just mock the single method.  You can achieve this with `spyOn` instead:

```
describe('TestController', function() {

var $controller, $scope, TestService;

beforeEach(module('testModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _TestService_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    TestService = _TestService_;
    spyOn(TestService, 'load').and.returnValue('bar');
    $controller = _$controller_('TestController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        TestService: TestService
    });
}));

it('should set $scope.data to bar when TestService.load is called',       function() {
        expect(TestService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect($scope.data).toEqual("bar");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Davin. I replaced my test with the code above and it's returning 'Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined' at the line where the spyOn is called. I changed it to: spyOn(TestService, 'load').andReturn('bar') and the test is green now. "and.return." is Jasmine 2.0 syntax, right?

Comment: must be Jasmine 2.0 then.  if `andReturn` works, that's great!

Answer (score 1):

In your `beforeEach` you are injecting in `_TestService_` and then overwriting the one you declared in the previous `beforeEach` via:

```
TestService = _TestService_;
```

Remove that code and your test should succeed.

Also there is no need to do this:

```
$provide.value("TestService", TestService)
```

Basically you're trying to use Angular's dependency injection when you're manually injecting things which is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Brocco. I removed the two lines as you suggested but the test still fails. It gives me: "Cannot read property 'load' of undefined". Looks like it's trying to call load on the TestService spyObj but it's still not finding the spyObj.

Comment: It appears to have been a combination of what I suggested and the spy issue that Davin showed you in his answer (which you accepted)